# How to get the value of TcxComboBox in DELPHI 10.3.3

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl

I hope I can get the answer that I want... I have read many things about it and found nothing
So here is the thing
I have a DBVERTICALGRID View that gets data from the database... (not important)
when I press a button which is Called Edit_btn I turn the EditorRow to a ComboBox Using :

```pascal
for I := 1 to Data_Sheet_.temp_Query.RecordCount do
    begin
     TcxComboBoxProperties(Job_ColorName.Properties.EditProperties).Items.Add(Data_Sheet_.temp_Query.FieldByName('Color_Name').AsString);
     Data_Sheet_.temp_Query.Next;
    end;
   Data_Sheet_.temp_Query.First;
```

And I get the proper result of populating the Combobox items by data in my database...
then I wanna get the Value of the that is changed by the user... (Let's say the data was 'White', Now he wants to change it to 'Blue' From the ComboBox Items), And I did the proper setting on the EditorRow to make the OnChange procedure work...
... the problem arises when I wanna show the selected value in the ComboBox through :

```pascal
procedure TBindingJobEdit_.Job_ColorNameEditPropertiesChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ShowMessage('HAHAHAH|'+' '+TcxComboBoxProperties(Job_ColorName.Properties.EditProperties).Items.Text);
end;
```

And I get all of the records in the database, But I only want the selected one like Red or Just Blue

[image: All Records of my database]

Comment: If you read the [`TcxComboBox` documentation](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/user-forms/components/tcxcombobox.html), you would see that the [`Properties.Items`](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/user-forms/properties/items-1.html) contains all of the items in the drop-down list, and the [`TcxComboBox.ItemIndex`](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/user-forms/properties/itemindex.html) contains the index of the selected item.

Comment: @RemyLebeau 
Yea I read bout it and I have MENTIONED in the question that it returns all of the values in the database, and I want the selected one... but as for `ItemIndex` I couldnt find anything , I mean there were no record of `ItemIndex` in its property and in case of my code , 
You may find `Combobox.ItemIndex` anywhere but in case of my code i couldnt find it

Comment: That is because you are accessing `TcxComboBoxProperties`, not the `TcxComboBox` itself.  `ItemIndex` is a property of `TcxComboBox` not of `TcxComboBoxProperties`.  The value you are looking for is in `TcxComboBox.Properties.Items[TcxComboBox.ItemIndex]`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tired the thing you said but you won't believe it.
`TcxComboBox.(Sometimes has Properties and sometimes it doesn't have)`
then when it has `Properties`, it doesn't have `Items` in it
What i mean totally is that there is no luck it

Comment: I do not understand what you are describing. Component properties don't just disappear and reappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer that I have found with the help of DevExpress Experts and Supporters
you can see the full description in this link and here is the line of code

```
procedure TBindingJobEdit_.Job_ColorNameEditPropertiesChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ShowMessage('HAHAHAH|'+' '+TcxComboBox(Sender).EditValue);
end;
```

and the link to the [Support Center](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t915112/how-to-get-the-value-of-tcxcombobox-in-delphi-10-3-3)

Answer (score 1):

To access to the Value of Cellule in Grid you must proceed like this:
Suppose that your view is jobview, so in your column you have an event inside Properties, **OnEditValueChange**, (NB: you can use **OnChange** of column or **OnEditValueChanged** of the view); so, your code become :

```cs
    procedure TBindingJobEdit_.Job_ColorNameEditPropertiesChange(Sender: TObject);
    var MyText: string; MyValue: Variant;
    begin
     MyValue:= jobview.Controller.SelectedRows[0].Values[Job_ColorName.Index];
     MyText:= jobview.Controller.SelectedRows[0].DisplayTexts[Job_ColorName.Index];
    
     ShowMessage('HAHAHAH|'+' '+MyText);
     //Or you can use MyValue (As ItemIndex of the combobox), in this case MyValue is Integer value.
    end;
```

i Hope you find your answer.

I modify my code like this

```cs
uses ...., cxDropDownEdit;

    TForm1 = class(TForm)
      Button1: TButton;
      procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      procedure cxComboBox1PropertiesEditValueChanged(Sender: TObject);
    Private
      Job_ColorName: TcxComboBox;
    Public
    end;
    
    implementation
    {$R *.dfm}
    
    procedure TFTeste.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Job_ColorName:= TcxComboBox.Create(Self);
      // Other code for Job_Colorname to assign Left, Top, Width, Populate Items, ....
      Job_ColorName.Properties.OnEditValueChanged:= cxComboBox1PropertiesEditValueChanged;
    end;
    
    procedure TFTeste.cxComboBox1PropertiesEditValueChanged(Sender: TObject);
    var MyText: string;
    begin      
      MyText:= TcxComboBox(Sender).Text;
      // or 
      MyText:= TcxComboBox(Sender).Properties.Items[TcxComboBox(Sender).ItemIndex];
    
      ShowMessage('HAHAHAH|'+' '+MyText);
    end;
    
    end.
```

Comment: this might work as well i have to check but the Combobox is created at runtime
and the answer was above I found it no the next question is how to assigne an onChange procedure to an object like Combobox at runtime like 
```Delphi
ComboBox1.OnChange := ????
```
this I dont know how